# Can't delte this cube

Tags: objects

[image]That black cube is just in the middle of my scene, I am pretty sure it is messing with the water flow, if anyone know how to fix it let me know. I have to get it ready soon for a video of mine.

Comment: What black cube? What scene? Water flow, where? We are not hacker, we cannot see inside your computer. Consider take a screenshot and specified what are you creating in this scene.

Comment: I forgot to press the add picture.